# grunt glob file with regex?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to read a file with grunt like this:

```
grunt.file.read(filepath [, options])
```

but my filepath is a regex:

```
src/dist/res/js/*.index.js
```

so I want to find all file end with `.index.js`, then read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt mostly is a tool with declarative configs, so if you need to read a sequence of files, you're probably doing something wrong.

Anyway your task can be implemented with next snippet

```
grunt.file.expand('src/dist/res/js/*.index.js').forEach((filePath) => {
    console.log(grunt.file.read(filePath))
})
```